# tf.data vs keras.utils.sequence performance

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to decide whether to use the existing keras.utils.sequence module or to switch to tf.data. From what I understand, tf.data optimizes performance by [overlapping training on GPU with pre-processing on the CPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets). But how does that compare to keras.utils.sequence and the keras data generator? From what I read [here](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) it seems that it's doing the same thing. Is there anything to gain by switching to tf.data ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both approaches overlap input data preprocessing with model training. `keras.utils.sequence` does this by running multiple Python processes, while [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) does this by running multiple C++ threads.

If your preprocessing is being done by a non-TensorFlow Python library such as [PIL](https://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), `keras.utils.sequence` may work better for you since multiple processes are needed to avoid contention on Python's global interpreter lock.

If you can express your preprocessing using TensorFlow operations, I would expect `tf.data` to give better performance.

Some other things to consider:

- `tf.data` is the recommended approach for building scalable input pipelines for [tf.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/overview#train_from_tfdata_datasets)
- `tf.data` is used more widely than `keras.utils.sequence`, so it may be easier to search for help with getting good performance.