# Performance of tf.data versus keras.Utils.sequence when augmenting data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

Working in COLAB with tensorflow 2.3 and its internal `tf.keras` .

I'm training a network that works on 2D images in input that really benefits from data augmentation (affine transforms, patch extraction, and intensity manipulation mainly). The input data fit all in memory so I don't have any disk reading bottleneck. The operations are a bit to be tailored to my data, so I prefer to implement them myself, when possible. I can do everything with numpy functions and keras generator functions. I've used `keras.sequence` to build my generator, as I understood that it was the best thing to do. On other sources, some people say that instead `tf.data` is more standard.

I've read on a previous question ( [tf.data vs keras.utils.sequence performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852831/tf-data-vs-keras-utils-sequence-performance) ) that both are supposed to be pre-processing data on CPU, but when I turn augmentation on, from the tensorboard profiler it seems like this isn't happening (50% time spent with GPU idled while the generator is running). It goes down to 10% if I turn the augmentation operations off and leave only the patch extraction. But they still don't seem to be overlapping.

So, should I just switch to `tf.data`? Is `tf.data` efficient if I need to write my own python code that works on numpy, or does it work well only if I can use its internal functions? Am I doing something wrong with `keras.utils.Sequence`?

Answer (score 1):

I would resort to using `tf.data.Dataset()` for its scalability and code cleanliness. Like you observed, it may be the case that `Sequence()` works even slower than you might have expected.

If you do use `tf.data.Dataset()` indeed you have to make sure you use the internal tensorflow functions, that is if you want the best performance possible. Otherwise, it is possible to use the https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function in order to implement custom Python code, such as numpy augmentation/manipulation.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of some good tutorials about how to use it? I need to do some very simple stuff (pick some slices from a 4D tensor, stack them in piles of 6 (channels) and apply some geometrical deformations/intensity shift). While keeping a list of the elements already extracted. Very easy in Python, but I don't know where to start in tf.data.Dataset

Comment: TF have done a great job with the documentation lately : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset